# I installed Ubuntu along side windows 10. My windows is gone and I still have 7GB used space for Ubuntu.

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I installed Ubuntu along side windows 10. I thought I had the windows but when my computer starts, Ubuntu starts and there is no option for dual boot.

I don't understand either my windows is gone or not. Moreover, I still have 7GB used space for Ubuntu and the rest appears as free space.

I'm attaching screenshot please can anyone help me understand what is happening?
Image 1. [System overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcfXJ.png) 
[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgfeo.png)
[Disk usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Tg5.png)

Thank you!

Comment: You have a full install of Ubuntu and it uses about 7GB. you installed it in a 8GB partition, leaving not much room. Rest of drive is unallocated. You must have choosen the "Erase entire drive" install option. Windows is gone. If you still want Windows you will have to restore from your backups. You do have backups?

Comment: @oldfred, amm I don't want Windows anymore and neither do I have backups. Can you please tell me how can I allow Ubuntu to utilize the rest of the drive as well instead of only 7GB?

Comment: Use gparted from live installer. Little key icon says it is mounted & it cannot be mounted to edit it.  Easiest is just to expand your one partition to what every size you like. But I normally suggest only 25 or 30GB for / (root) and use rest of disk for /home or data partition(s). Somewhat like one large file cabinet with dividers or one with drawers. You still have separators/folders so some organization. You still need to develop a backup plan for your data.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools I prefer rsync as then I have more control, but have to set it up.